# str_match_all with line break?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

This extracts the text between 'here' and 'text'

```
test <- "here is some text"
str_match_all(test, "here(.*?)text")
# [[1]]
# [,1]                [,2]       
# [1,] "here is some text" " is some "
```

But the line breaks interfer - how can we extract everything in between 'here' and 'text' ***including*** line breaks?

```r
test <- "here 
is 
some 
text"

str_match_all(test, "here(.*?)text")
# [[1]]
# [,1] [,2]
```

Comment: Not sure if we can do `gs` in `r` but here it shows that python can handle it. https://regex101.com/r/SvmFqT/2/

Answer (score 3):

One can use the whitespace character selection option "*\\s*".  This string "*(.|\\s)*" represents any character **or** whitespace.

```
str_match_all(test, "here((.|\\s)*?)text")


[[1]]
     [,1]                    [,2]            [,3]
[1,] "here \nis \nsome \ntext" " \nis \nsome \n" "\n"
```

**EDIT**
Here is another form which is working better (Only two parts, but still an extra line break at the end):

```
str_match_all(test, "here([[[:alnum:]]|[[:space:]]]+?)text")
[[1]]
     [,1]                      [,2]             
[1,] "here \nis \nsome \ntext" " \nis \nsome \n"
```

Comment: This is very close but the last `\n` is unexpected?